# SQL 2005 Select data where conversion fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there any way for me to test a data conversion in a select statement and only return rows where the conversion fails?

IE:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE CONVERT(datetime, [colA]) = NULL
```

I'm open to any SQL hacks/trickery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use isdate

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE isdate(colA)  = 0
```

See also [Trouble With ISDATE And Converting To SMALLDATETIME](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Trouble_With_ISDATE_And_Converting_To_SMALLDATETIME)